# How to append code verbatim to .bashrc?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

As an example: When installing `pyenv`, you're required to add

```
export PATH="/home/user/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

to your `.bashrc` file.

However, the usual `echo '..' >> ~/.bashrc` will evaluate the statements before appending. How do you properly append such statements to a file using the command line without evaluation?

Comment: This will not evaluate the commands, it will only print them into your `~/.bashrc`. Either provide more information about your system and setup, or open `~/.bashrc` in a text editor and write the lines by hand

Comment: @j-money This was merely meant as an example. I have noticed that there may be a discrepancy between the results of using `echo '..'` vs `echo ..` and as such, simply piping line by line into the file may indeed solve the issue. Nevertheless, steeldriver has provided a concise and scalable solution.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd suggest a [here document](http://bash.cumulonim.biz/BashGuide(2f)InputAndOutput.html#Heredocs_And_Herestrings)

```
$ cat >> .bashrc <<'EOF'
export PATH="/home/user/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
EOF
```

So long as the `EOF` word (which can be anything) is quoted, no shell expansion of the body takes place.

Answer (score 6):

> However, the usual `echo '..' >> ~/.bashrc` will evaluate the statements before appending. How do you properly append such statements to a file using the command line without evaluation?

No it won't. Anything inside of single-quotes is *completely un-evaluated*. You can use
`echo 'eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc`  without any worry that anything will be interpreted. The only character of any significance in a single-quoted string is a single-quote (which ends the string, and cannot be escaped.)

Answer (score 2):

You can add `\` in front of special characters.

For example:

```
echo export PATH=\"/home/user/.pyenv/bin:\$PATH\"
```

gives the following result:

```
export PATH="/home/user/.pyenv/bin:$PATH"
```

so the quotation marks and the `$PATH` are still there.